# using HTML5 video tag in a simple rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, routes, erb

inside index.html.erb there is the following code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
      <source src="truffle1.mp4"/>
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I am not sure where to put my mp4 video file so I put it at several places.
Next I fire up the rails server and use Chrome to open the index page.  I see the black video frame but it does not play.  and when I try open video in a new window. I get
No route matches [GET] "/admin/truffle1.mp4" 
(note admin is just the namespace for the controller).

---

seems like this is a rails routing problem...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you say `src="truffle1.mp4"`you're telling Rails to look for that file from the current route (you're probably on localhost:3000/admin if you're trying it on a local server, so it's looking in localhost:3000/admin/truffle1.mp4).

You could try giving it the route from the home of your app like so: `src="/assets/media/truffle1.mp4"`, and put the file in that directory (you'll probably have to create it).

**EDIT**

Following the answer provided by @Pragnesh Vaghela, I managed to make it work. Your first intuition was right. You're missing routing if you want to have your videos in /assets/videos. When you say:

```
<%= video_tag "truffle1.mp4", :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

the server will look for the file in all the assets directories that have been routed (by default: stylesheets, images, and javascripts). If you put your video in images, it should work, for example. If you want to have the /assets/videos directory searched also, you have to add the following line to your config/application.rb file:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
```

You can put it under the line that says:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

I believe.

Hope this works.

Comment: This provides a working solution, but the solution below is the correct one.

Comment: @NoahClark Yup. Wasn't aware of the video_tag. Rails never ceases to surprise me :)

Comment: I tried BOTH solutions.  I am still getting No route matches [GET] "/assets/media/truffle1.mp4"

Comment: I tried @Pragnesh Vaghela 's answer, played with it for a bit, looked at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for a bit more, and got it to work. Posted on the edit.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but to add paths to assets, the rails guides uses the .join method instead of hard-coded slashes: config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "videos")

Comment: I was able to link to the video but it remains black.

Comment: Hello! How I can add speed controls to player? It s possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the video_tag helper which builds an HTML 5  tag. Video files are loaded from 'public/videos' by default.

```
<%= video_tag "truffle1.mp4", :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/assets/truffle1.mp4"

Comment: Can you paste your routes snippet